# ConfigMap being mounted as a folder instead of file

Tags: kubernetes

I have a problem mounting 2 files in a pod, one is being treated as a directory for some reason (maybe stupid one, but I looked and looked, couldn't find a solution).

in my `config` folder there's 2 files:

```
config
|- log4j.properties
|- server.main.properties
```

Running `StatefulSet`, here's the Volumes part of the manifest file:

```
containers:
 ...
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/confluent/config/log4j.properties
          name: log4j-properties
          subPath: log4j.properties
        - mountPath: /usr/local/confluent/config/server.properties
          name: server-properties
          subPath: server.properties
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
    - name: log4j-properties
      configMap:
        name: log4j-properties
        defaultMode: 0777
    - name: server-properties
      configMap:
        name: server-properties
        defaultMode: 0777
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: confluent-persistent-storage
  spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1Gi
```

Created ConfigMaps:

```
kubectl create configmap server-properties --from-file=config/server.main.properties
kubectl create configmap log4j-properties --from-file=config/log4j.properties
```

`kubectl describe pod` gives mounted volumes as:

```
    Volumes:
  confluent-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  confluent-persistent-storage-confluent-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  server-properties:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      server-properties
    Optional:  false
  log4j-properties:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      log4j-properties
    Optional:  false
```

It's being initialized for 5-6 minutes and in logs I can see that server.properties is not a file, but a folder, and when I exec into pod, I can see that the actual folder is been created instead of file.. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> subPath: server.properties

Wouldn't you want to use it as below?

> subPath: server.main.properties

Comment: I have server.dev.properties, server.staging.properties, and server.main.properties in my config folder, that's why configmap was created from server.main.properties. Could this be a reason, because it doesn't make a sense to me, was thinking that I refer to configmap Name instead of file?

Comment: the file names are within the ConfigMap, right?

Comment: well, I guess it is, how can I then rename it to server.properties on the pod?

Comment: I think that is what you are doing, since the `mountPath:` only contains `server.properties`

Comment: so I should just change subPath then?! i knew it would be something "stupid" that never occurred to me :)